# Adding an executable to Plank

Tags: plank, app-shortcuts

Using Elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya 64-bit.

I use an app called Isoplex.  It's run directly from an executable which I have stored in the Downloads directory.  Runs just fine by double clicking on the file from Files.

How do I pin this to Plank?  The icon appears while running Isoplex, but right-clicking doesn't let me pin Isoplex to Plank.

Is there a way to do this?  Alternately, can I add Isoplex to my Applications list in the upper-left corner? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Create `.desktop` extension file in `~/.local/share/applications`. For example:

```
scratch-text-editor ~/.local/share/applications/isoplex.desktop
```

And write this in there:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=command to run here
Name=visible name here
Comment=comment here
Icon=icon path here
```

You must manually find and assign it the path to the executable file, and the icon. Don't forget to make the file executable (`chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/isoplex.desktop`).

Then you can drag&drop the desktop file onto Plank or launch it from Slingshot and then 'Keep in dock'.

Comment: Okay, everything went okay, but I don't see any way to get scratch to save the file.  Is it saved when I close scratch?  The icon doesn't show up on the panel.  Sigh.

Comment: @JeffreyNeedle Yes, Scratch saves files when changing. If you did everything correctly, the icon should appear in Slingshot (applications menu). Place your result (isoplex.desktop) on Pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Now there exists this app:

https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor.desktop

Very useful!